# How do I add an empty array to an object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

basically I have an array that I pull data from. I would like to add a new array to it so I can pull additional data.

```
var myArray.libraries = []
```

gets items added via a for loop like this:

```
for(var x=0; x < items.length; x++){
    myArray.libraries ({ name: items(x).name, state: items(x).state});
}
```

that works great and I can get what I need from `myArray.libraries .name`. I need to add something like "books" so each entry can have it's list of books. There could be 1 or more books.

to be clear I'm using angular so I use something like this to output for each library:

```
<div ng-repeat="library in libraries">
    <p>{{library.name}}</p>
</div>
```

I just need to add `books` so I can loop through each book in that library:

```
<div ng-repeat="book in libraries.books">
    <p>{{book.name}}</p>
</div>
```

I tried using `myArray.libraries.books = []` but that didn't add the collect to each library. I also tried `myArray.libraries.push({ books: { } })` but that didn't have any affect and gave me an error that I couldn't push to `myArray.libraries.books` since books didn't exist.

EDIT

Here's some sample code. I'm using angular but the principle should be the same:

```
$scope.libraries= [];

//start loop to get the installations
for (var x = 0; x < res.rows.length; x++) {
    $scope.libraries.push({ ... , books: []});

    //run a new query to get the additional libraries info
    var booksQuery = query to get books;
    //run query to get results and loop through them
        for (var i = 0;i < res2.rows.length; i++) {
            $scope.libraries[x].books.push({ name: res2.rows.item(i).prodName });
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

I ran some tests and it turns out when I do my second database call it doesn't know the original `$scope` exists.

Comment: Your array should be inside the $scope

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, you have an array, yet you're treating it like an object adding named keys to it, so it's no longer an array. The loop doesn't seem to do anything, it just overwrites the same property on each iteration, and now you want to add another named key to the array that isn't really an array anymore ?

Comment: @Fals - it is, I was just simplifying it

Answer (score 2):

Try as follows:

```
for(var x=0; x < items.length; x++){
    myArray.libraries ({ name: items(x).name, state: items(x).state, books: []});
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: I'm just really confused, is `myArray.libraries` an array, an object or a function ?

Comment: As per the code you've posted, it seems like it's an array, containing objects inside. I've just added another key to the object you are pushing named books, that's an empty array as your question stated you wanted to do.

Comment: Now I'm more confused, I'm not the OP ?

Comment: my bad :) Did not realize you wheren't the OP

Comment: @taxicala - it was my question not @adeneo's. Also, what you suggested placed `books` in the array but I can't push to it. When I do `myArray.libraries.books.push({...})` I'm being told `Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: I'm running that inside a nested loop. I tried `myArray.libraries[x].books.push({...})` but that had issues as well. `x` is the key for the `libraries` loops and I'm using `i` for the `books` loop

Comment: Thats because you will have to iterate your libraries array in order to push to each library.books array. You cant access each of the libraries without iterating or at least knowing the index of it. If you do `myArray.libraries[0].books` you will be able to push something to the first library stored in your libraries array.

Comment: You should address the angular bit as well. Libraries.books should probably be nested in the library loop and be library.books.

Comment: I did that and got an error `Unable to get property 'books' of undefined or null reference`. However, I can console.log out the array and it is there for each library

Answer (score 1):

Basically the problem is that you are trying to push array to an array. You can push another array to your `libraries`, but to access books you have to use index to access specific item like `myArray.libraries[0].books[0]`

So I assume you have to change `myArray.libraries.push({ books: { } })` to `myArray.libraries.push({ books: [] })`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a plunker for you. Please refer to

"http://plnkr.co/edit/0FKg2fbe4CY11Oz6aSBF?p=preview"

```
$scope.libraries = {
    books : [
  {"name" : "book1"},
  {"name" : "book2"},
  {"name" : "book3"}
      ]


  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the plunker, and that's the result I want. I'm trying to figure out how to create an empty `books` inside my array so I can push new items to it via a loop.

Comment: When I try that it just adds `books` to `myArray` not `myArray.libraries` and it place each book it's on array instead of grouping them...

Comment: I am not able to collect, Can you please send the updated code?

Comment: I have updated the plunker for your review. Please chek "http://plnkr.co/edit/0FKg2fbe4CY11Oz6aSBF?p=preview"

Comment: I'm attempting something similar to what you're suggesting. Before I add `books` if I run this in the second loop `$scope.libraries[x].books` I get an empty array, as expected. but when I run `$scope.libraries[x].books.push({...})` i get the error `Unable to get property 'books' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: I think there is a problem in the way you are using $scope.libraries[x]. What is x here. As the first loop has executed, x will be 1 more than the size of array. I think that is the issue.

Comment: I'm making a second database select call inside the second for loop. It's finishing the loop before the db runs and only passes the final value through. I have to figure it how to do this differently now.

Comment: To resolve this problem, please use callback function.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

DB calls are async, so the 2nd db call shouldn't be in loop. Please check if this works

```
$scope.libraries = [];  

  init();

  function init() {
    // do the first db transaction
  }

  // transaction1 callback
  function trans1Callback(result) {    
    addBooks(result);
  }

  var i = 0;

  function addBooks(result) {
      // to stop iteration at the end of records
      if (i >= result.rows.length) {
        return;
      }
      var item = result.rows.item(i);
      var data = {name: item.name, state: item.state, books: []};
      // do the second db transaction

      // transaction2 callback
      function trans2Callback(result2) {

          for (var j =0; j < result2.rows.length; j++) {
              var book = result.rows.item(j);
              data.books.push({ name: book.prodName });
          }
          // push to scope libraries
          $scope.libraries.push(data);
          // do increment
          i++;
          // Call addBooks again to process next record
          addBooks(result);
      }

  }
```

Comment: added some code so you can see more info, this includes some angular stuff too. Didn't want to overload the sample with my db calls though

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please let me know, if it solves your prob