# In Angular, how can I use ng-repeat to pass a variable to that triggers it repeat number?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my app I do a database call to get a list of elements to display using `ng-reat`, this works fine. Inside that list is another list. That depends on another DB call.

I'd like to pass an id and repeat an element the number of results I get back and output their data. Something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="library in libraries">
    <p>Read our books:</p>
    <p ng-repeat="book in books">{{book.title}}</p>
</div>
```

I thought about this:

```
<p ng-repeat="book in getBooks({library.id}) track by $index">{{book.title}}</p>
```

this use something like this to trigger the number of repeats and the values:

```
$scope.getBooks = function(id){
    ...run my database query using the id...
    ...update my scope to include the books...
    ....**magic**...
}
```

but I'm not sure if that will work and how to update my scope to include the book title. I've used this to repeat an x number of times but not include an updated `$scope`

Comment: Store the books on the library in which they reside. I would probably pre-fetch them. That would make your life easier. So scope contains `libraries` and each library has books (`book in library.books`...).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<p ng-repeat="book in library.books">` ? Hard to guess, since you didn't post your data.

Comment: You should build the model up properly in the controller and so each library has a books property.  Then repeat over the `book in library.books`.  Don't put the `libraries` on scope until the join is done, easier on angular's digest cycle.

Comment: To make your upcoming $scope issues easier, make a directive library, ng-repeat and push the library into the directive and then each library directive can get it's own books.  If you need all the books pre-fetched, then push the data consumption into a factory and have the controller get the data from the factory.

Comment: I have to do multiple database calls: 1 to get all my libraries another to set/push the books info. I can't get the second to run in a loop synchronously. So the loop finishes before my database calls and I get an error. That's why I can't set the libraries.books up first.

Comment: @KnowHowSolutions - that wen WAY over my head.

Comment: I have `$scope.libraries.books` created already, it's just that `books` is empty. I need to populate books for each library to be used in my ng-repeat.

Comment: You can see my issues with the database queries here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673117/how-do-i-add-an-empty-array-to-an-object-array/30673416#30673416

Answer (score 0):

Along with Corbin, my solution would be to pre-load the data.  Do that with an Angular factory object.

```
 angular.module('appName')
        .factory('DataManager', DataManager);

    function DataManager($log, $timeout, DataService) {
        var mngr, config = getConfig();  // any default values

        $log.debug('DataManager Init');

        mngr = {
            CurrentSearchTerm: null,
            Libraries: [],
            Abort: abort,
            GetData: getData  // Function call to get data.
        };

        // This call is your main ajax call, it could be one call to get the
        // full dataset of lib + books in json format.  Or multiple calls.
        function getData(){
            DataService.getData().then(function(response){
             //  ...parse data, etc...loop and :
             mngr.Libraries.push(parsedDataItem);
            };
        }


        return mngr;
   }
```

Inject that into your controller.  Then you loop over that data.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="library in mngr.Libraries">
     <!-- now you should have library.Books which was already sent down in the factory payload. -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

Again to make your life a bit easier use a directive, each repeat push it's data into a directive:

```
<library data="library">
```

Which allows you to have a nice template and scope into just that one library.

```
angular('appName').directive('library',function(){
            return{
            restrict:'E',
            replace:true,
            templateUrl:'library.view.html',
            scope:{
                data:'='
            },
            controller:function($scope,$log){
                // Here $scope.data === library from your ngRepeat!
            }
        };
});
```

Lastly, if you wanted an ondemand loading of the books, in the directive you can add a method to your DataManager to 'getBooks' for that one library object.

Does that make more sense?